# How to get filename while SparkStreaming on HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to listen file updating on HDFS, I can get input streaming by

```
JavaDStream<String> lines=jssc.textFileStream("hdfs://xxxxx")
```

Could I get filename string of newcome files at the same time and how?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code. Hope it helps...
There is method to get file path from rdd and remaining logic to go foreachrdd

```
public static String getFilePath(JavaRDD<String> rdd) {
    UnionPartition upp = (UnionPartition) rdd.partitions().iterator().next();
    NewHadoopPartition npp = (NewHadoopPartition) upp.parentPartition();
    String filePath = npp.serializableHadoopSplit().value().toString();
    return filePath;
}

JavaDStream<String> dstream = jssc.textFileStream("hdfs://xxxxx");
dstream.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {
        String path = getFilePath(rdd);
        // Other logic with rdd
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much,I'll try it